# How to verify / troubleshoot AVD debug key

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, signing, android-virtual-device

I'm trying the HelloMapView example found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Problem I'm having is that when I run my application, none of the map tiles will load... I heard this is usually do to my google maps api key not being correct. I tried signing my app with a key that I generated from google, but the application still wouldn't load the tiles into the map. I can zoom and effect other features of the map, everything except for actually loading the tiles. I was reading that the eclipse (which I'm using) will automatically generate a key for you, but that's not happening. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should get an api-key for your debug key.

- Go to http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html
- Run `keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore` from a shell
- Paste your Certificate fingerprint in the link
- Add the api-key to your layout. it should look like [this](http://www.google.com/glm/mmap/a/api?fp=94:1E:43:49:87:73%3aBB%3aE6%3aA6:88%3aD7:20%3aF1:8E%3aB5:98).